# Internal energy variation of a thermodynamic tank

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, heat-engine

First of all, I apologize if some specific terms are not accurate but I'm using the translations that Google gives me.

The test where I found the problem asks to calculate the variation of internal energy (*ΔU1*) of a thermal reservoir (the **cold** one), in a generic reversabile heat engine cycle. He gives me the temperature of the colder sink (*T1*), of the hot source (*T2*), and the work (*W*) that the enige produces in a single cycle.
The point is that I have always considered the thermal reservoir as something able to keep its temperature constant. The heat transfer should be an isothermal transformation and the variation of internal energy should be zero. Clearly I'm wrong, but I don't understand where is the problem.

I've attached the text of the question (it's in Italian, but you probably just need the data...). I've erased the equations that I didn't write personally. I know for sure that the second answer is correct.

Thanks!!

[image: problem text]

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the temperature of the cold reservoir doesn't change (or, to be more precise, a change cannot be measured) doesn't mean its internal energy doesn't change. It simply means the increase in internal energy does not cause enough of a temperature change to be able to measure. Think about throwing a hot stone into the colder ocean. The stone transfers heat to the ocean increasing its internal energy. But the ocean is so massive, the change in its temperature is so small as to be immeasurable.

The only think you need to calculate the increase in internal energy of the cold reservoir is to determine the heat, $Q_L$, that is transferred to it as that will equal the internal energy increase. You can find that using the Carnot efficiency and the work that was  done.

> Ok, probably I'm mixing the reservoir with the gas (for example) of
> the engine. We can talk about a isothermal transformation when we are
> considering the working substance of the engine. While, from the point
> of view of the reservoir, we are simply passing to it some energy (in
> terms of heating, but I could be also mechanical work) causing a
> variation of the internal energy. Am I right?

It's not clear which internal energy you mean at the end of your comment.

First of all, though I can't read the problem statement, it is clearly a Carnot engine cycle problem based on the correct answer. Consequently, if you are talking about the internal energy of the system (working substance), then the isothermal processes do not cause any change (variation) in the internal energy of the working substance because each heat transfer exactly equals the work done by or on the working substance. Applying the first law *to the system* for the isothermal processes, $\Delta U=Q-W$, means that the change (variation) in internal energy of the system is zero. The variations in internal energy occur only during the reversible adiabatic processes.

So if it is the system you are talking about, you are not correct since there is no internal energy variation during the isothermal processes.

If you are talking about the reservoirs, then obviously the internal energy of the hot reservoir decreases by an amount equal to $Q_{H}$. The internal energy of the cold reservoir increases by an amount equal to $Q_{L}$. The difference between the changes, $Q_{H}-Q_L$, then equals the work done by the cycle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok,  probably I'm mixing the reservoir with the gas (for example) of the engine. We can talk about a isothermal transformation when we are considering the working substance of the engine. While, from the point of view of the reservoir, we are simply passing to it some energy (in terms of heating, but I could be also mechanical work) causing a variation of the internal energy. Am I right?

Comment: @StefanoCalifano I've updated my answer to respond to your follow up question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, perfect, I was talking about the reservoir. I was just a bit confused but the answer now is very clear... Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For a finite reservoir, the first law tells us that $$\Delta U=MC\Delta T=Q$$So, the temperature change is :  $$\Delta T=\frac{Q}{MC}$$In the limit of infinite thermal inertia MC, $$\Delta T--> 0$$while $Q = \Delta U$ remains finite..